# GUI doesnt open for Entry string

Tags: python, tkinter

I keep getting the error time "data 'startdate_info' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'" but it doesn't open the GUI for the data Entries. It should open a GUI for start date, end date, ticker and inspect string entry. Those strings should go into:

```
newtime = yf.download('ticker_info', start = 'startdate_info', end = 'enddate_info')
```

But for some reason I keep getting stuck on this line 55.

```
import yfinance as yf
import pandas as pd
import pyautogui
from tkinter import *
import keyboard
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import pyplot

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("450x550")

startdate = StringVar()
start_date = Label(text = "Enter start date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
start_date.place(x = 15, y = 70)
startdate_entry = Entry(textvariable = startdate, width = "30")
startdate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 120)

enddate = StringVar()
end_date = Label(text = "Enter end date in YYYY-MM-DD format: ")
end_date.place(x = 15, y = 170)
enddate_entry = Entry(textvariable = enddate, width = "30")
enddate_entry.place(x = 15, y = 220)

tickerE = StringVar()
ticker_label = Label(text = "Ticker symbol:  ")
ticker_label.place(x = 15, y = 270)
ticker = Entry(textvariable = tickerE, width = "30")
ticker.place(x = 15, y = 320)

inspectE = StringVar()
inspect_label = Label(text = "What would you like to analyze  ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 270)
inspect_label = Label(text = "(Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume)? ")
inspect_label.place(x = 15, y = 320)
inspect = Entry(textvariable = inspectE, width = "30")
inspect.place(x = 15, y = 370)



def save_info():
    startdate_info = startdate.get()
    enddate_info = enddate.get()
    ticker_info = tickerE.get()
    inspect_info = inspectE.get()
    return ticker_info, inspect_info, startdate_info, enddate_info
save_info()

search = Button(screen,text = "Search", width = "30", height = "2", command = save_info, bg = "grey")
search.place(x = 14, y = 410)

ticker_info, inspect_info, startdate_info, enddate_info = save_info()

newtime = yf.download('ticker_info', start = 'startdate_info', end = 'enddate_info')
print(newtime)
def adjusted_close(ticker_info, newtime):
    newtime[inspect_info].plot()
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel(inspect_info)
    plt.title(ticker_info + " " + inspect_info + " "  + "Data")
    plt.show()
adjusted_close(ticker_info, newtime)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed strings to `yf.download()`:

```
newtime = yf.download('ticker_info', start = 'startdate_info', end = 'enddate_info')
```

You should pass the variables:

```
newtime = yf.download(ticker_info, start=startdate_info, end=enddate_info)
```

Also you should not executed the function just after creating the `Entry` widgets because there is nothing input yet.  You should execute the function inside `save_info()`:

```py
def save_info():
    startdate_info = startdate.get()
    enddate_info = enddate.get()
    ticker_info = tickerE.get()
    inspect_info = inspectE.get()
    print(startdate_info, enddate_info, ticker_info, inspect_info, sep=",")
    newtime = yf.download(ticker_info, start=startdate_info, end=enddate_info)
    print(newtime)
```

---

Below is a cut-down example based on your code:

```py
from tkinter import *
import yfinance as yf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

screen = Tk()
screen.geometry("450x580")

startdate = StringVar()
start_date = Label(text="Enter start date in YYYY-MM-DD format:")
start_date.place(x=15, y=70)
startdate_entry = Entry(textvariable=startdate, width=30)
startdate_entry.place(x=15, y=120)

enddate = StringVar()
end_date = Label(text="Enter end date in YYYY-MM-DD format:")
end_date.place(x=15, y=170)
enddate_entry = Entry(textvariable=enddate, width=30)
enddate_entry.place(x=15, y=220)

tickerE = StringVar()
ticker_label = Label(text="Ticker symbol:")
ticker_label.place(x=15, y=270)
ticker = Entry(textvariable=tickerE, width=30)
ticker.place(x=15, y=320)

inspectE = StringVar()
inspect_label = Label(text="What would you like to analyze")
inspect_label.place(x=15, y=370)
inspect_label = Label(text="(Open, High, Low, Close, Adj Close, Volume)?")
inspect_label.place(x=15, y=420)
inspect = Entry(textvariable=inspectE, width=30)
inspect.place(x=15, y=470)

def save_info():
    startdate_info = startdate.get()
    enddate_info = enddate.get()
    ticker_info = tickerE.get()
    inspect_info = inspectE.get()
    print(startdate_info, enddate_info, ticker_info, sep=",")
    newtime = yf.download(ticker_info, start=startdate_info, end=enddate_info)
    print(newtime)
    # plot it
    newtime[inspect_info].plot()
    plt.xlabel("Date")
    plt.ylabel(inspect_info)
    plt.title(f"{ticker_info} {inspect_info} Data")
    plt.show()

search = Button(screen, text="Search", width="30", height="2", command=save_info, bg="grey")
search.place(x=14, y=510)

screen.mainloop()
```

Comment: I still get the error. "No objects to concatenate" but the GUI Never Opens. GUI Should Open And Prompt User for Those Fields.

Comment: It is because the `ticker` entry is overlay by the `inspect_label` (both put at (15,270)), so you cannot input `ticker` and it cause `tikcer_info` empty.

Comment: Even when they aren't on the same location it won't open the GUI. I made your suggested changes and still have No objects to concatenate- I can't enter the objects because the GUI won't open.

Comment: I added a cut-down example that works for me.  So if the GUI does not open in your case, there are issues somewhere else.

Comment: Okay the GUI opens now. When I enter the time range and ticker symbol I get the data I need in the console. But how do I get it to run the bottom graph function after pressing the button?

Comment: @ColterGrantRobinson Answer updated with the plot.